# BibTeX file is not compatible with Springer svmono class

Tags: bibtex, natbib, harvard-style, sv-classes

In the Springer provided template for a monograph, I am unable to use a BibTeX file for the references.

I have made a `.bib` file, named `DG_Refrences`, containing all the details of necessary references.

Now in the Springer provided template for a monograph, named `book.tex`, before the last line `\end{document}`, I added

```
\bibliographystyle{havard}
\bibliography{DG_References}
```

My Tex file reads as follows:

%----------------------------------------------------

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap]{SVmono}

                       % choose options for [] as required from the list
                       % in the Reference Guide

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
                             % see the list of further useful packages
                             % in the Reference Guide
```

%---This portion I have added, but on a click the hyperlinks does not give any link to go--

```
\usepackage{natbib}             
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true,plainpages=false,colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

%-----------------------------------------------------------------

```
\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program




\begin{document}

\author{Authors Name(s)}
\title{Title goes here}

\maketitle

\frontmatter

\include{dedic}
\include{foreword}
\include{preface}
\include{acknow}

\tableofcontents

\include{acronym}


\mainmatter
\include{part}
\include{Chapter1/Chapter1}
\include{appendix}


\backmatter
\include{glossary}
\include{solutions}



\bibliographystyle{havard}
\bibliography{DG_References}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

%----------------------------------------------------

But when I cite some reference, like `\cite{wu2007duality}`, the generated pdf file is giving a `?` symbol. Please help.

I am also unable to use the `hyperref` package in the Springer template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Can you provide minimal working example? And for the bibtex to work you need to run:`latex` then `bibtex` then `latex` again.

Comment: I am really thankful to you Tahtisilma. Once I run: latex then bibtex then latex again, it works. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Dr. Tahtisilma, please help for the hyperef part. I am also unable to use the hyperref package in the Springer template.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide small example (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that does not work? Put four spaces before each line to format it as code.

Comment: @user144660 OK, as the first part of the question is the 'classic' LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX issue, I'm minded to close as a dupe of our 'standard' question on that. On `hyperref`, with a journal template it's normally not a good idea to add _anything_ that you don't absolutely require. As such, I'd say you should simply not do this.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot get the code in your posting to compile, in part because there doesn't seem to be a bibliography *style file* named "harvard.bst".

However, there exists a LaTeX *package* called [harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard); its main file is called `harvard.sty`. Note that because this is package, it needs to be loaded with a `\usepackage` instruction in the preamble rather than a `\bibliographystyle` instruction in the body of the document.

The `harvard` package also provides seven bibliography styles for formatting references according to various guidelines. They are `agsm`, `apsr`, `dcu`, `jmr`, `jphysicsB`, `kluwer`, and `nederlands`. If you want to use one of these styles, use `\bibliographystyle{...}` to load them. (Aside: The `harvard` package was one of the first packages that facilitated so-called authoryear-style citations. To this day, authoryear-style citations are sometimes also called "harvard-style" citations. By now though, there are quite a few more citation management packages that implement authoryear-style citations under BibTeX. The best-known of these may be `natbib`.)

You also mention that you want to enable the creation of hyperlinks from the citation callouts to the corresponding items in the bibliography. In that case, rather than loading the `harvard` package, it's better to load the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages. (The `har2nat` package, as you can probably guess, translates the citation commands provided by the `harvard` package into instructions that are understood by the macros of the `natbib` package, so that you can keep using one of the seven styles mentioned above.) Of course, if you don't use one of the styles provided by the `harvard` package, you needn't load `har2nat`; just load `natbib`.

The following simplified version of your code illustrates how you might proceed. I've used the `kluwer` bibliography style just as an example; obviously, you should choose a bibliography style that meets your specific needs and requirements.

[image]

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap]{svmono}
\usepackage{filecontents}  % make this example self-contained
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
\@article{something,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Random Thoughts",
  journal= "Great Communications",
  year   = 3001,
  volume = 1,
  issue  = 1,
  pages  = "1-100",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{mathptmx,helvet,courier,type1cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}      
\bibliographystyle{kluwer} % choose bib style that meets your needs

\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true, plainpages=false,
            colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citet{something}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user144660 - Did this answer provide (roughly) the information you need? If so, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.